# LFTP is running infinately inside a container in a gitlab pipline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, lftp

I was using the CI of gitlab after successful configurations and worked for two days no issues but as of yesterday once it gets to the point of sending files via ftp after building, it just keeps running till the container timeout after an hour. if there some sort of limit with regards to ftp connection or somethings of sorts?

This is the section of the .gitlab-ci which is the last set of commands

```
- echo "Initiating Push site:Staging."
- ls
- lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; open $FTP_HOST; user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS; mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose . .; bye"
```

This is the situation on gitlab

[image: deployment history]

[image: final response of failed pipeline]